# I'm a UK citizen/resident employed remotely by a US company. What's the chances of getting an H1B visa?

Tags: usa, uk, h1b-visas, working-visas, visa-sponsors

I'm a UK citizen working in London. For three years, I have been a writer employed by a company based in the USA. It's fair to say I'm indispensable but I do not have any formal writing qualifications.

I want to ask my employer about sponsoring a work visa for me so I can stay in America for a while. From what I understand, an H1B is the best option? But before I bother them, I'd like to know if I'm overlooking something and it's a waste of time? Or is there a chance?

The biggest issue is that I can work remotely, meaning there is no need for me to be in the country. On the flip side of that, surely if I'm earning their money, they'd prefer it if I spent it in their economy and their tax system?

Comment: This would be better asked on [expats.se] Stack Exchange

Comment: @Midavalo thanks! I'll move this there.

Comment: Are you working as an employee or a contractor?  Are they paying payroll taxes?  If so, to which jurisdiction?

Comment: @phoog good questions. I'm an employee. I am paying my taxes directly to the UK. I'm unsure if they are paying payroll taxes but I know everything they do is 100% according to the law, so if they are supposed to be paying payroll taxes to the US, then they will be. They have employees all around the world.

Comment: An L1visa might be better.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan interesting, first I've heard of that, I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: Moved to here: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21611/im-a-uk-citizen-resident-employed-remotely-by-a-us-company-whats-the-chances

Comment: Do you get a W-2 form or a 1099 form at the beginning of every year summarizing your pay for the previous year?  If the latter then you are being paid as a contractor.  I find it hard to imagine that they're doing it any other way.